# solr4.X Index data for parent and sub childs fields (one item with multiple products info) - Nested doc

Tags: solr, parent-child, nested-lists

In solr 4
How can post multiple sub fields

Like I have Items and it's related multiple products.
Ex.:
Item:
    id, Name, url, item_description
    Products1: id, product_name, product_description
    Products2: id, product_name, product_description
    ......
    ......

Single Item contain multiple products.

```
<doc>
<field name="id">123</item>
<field name="name">Main Name</item>
<field name="description">Main Description</item>
<field name="Products">
    <field name="product">
        <field name="id">1</field>
        <field name="product_name">Product name 1</field>
        <field name="product_desc">Product Description 1</field>
    </field>
    <field name="product">
        <field name="id">1</field>
        <field name="product_name">Product name 1</field>
        <field name="product_desc">Product Description 1</field>
    </field>
    ......
    ......
</field>
</doc>
.....
.....
```

Comment: I am looking for the solution, too. Have you solved the problem?